# Concept Behind Advance salary and remaining salary

Tags: sql, reporting

I have developed a project (employee management system), now I am on reporting part.

I want to show advance and remaining salary to the user. For this, I am thinking to put the calculated value inside a `remaining_salary` column of database. However, I saw an article in which it was mentioned that you should never put calculated values inside database, best practice is to do calculation on form.

If I do not put calculated value inside database then how can I show advance and remaining salary to the user?

Comment: @moodywoody: The question was there, only it didn't look much like one (neither grammatically nor punctuationally).

Comment: What is advance salary? What is remaining salary? What is salary? (yeah, that's a legitimate question). Are they columns in the database's tables? Which ones are calculated on other columns? Which ones are changed? What are the relationships between those columns/values? In short, adding the tables you have and some sample data would really help.

Comment: Is it OK to put calculated value inside database fields as anyone can directly take advantage of it.

Comment: So if this is about whether or not you should put calculated values into a DB can somebody make the title reflect this?

Comment: @San: If you can show the result after calculation, then what is the need of storing the calculated values?

Comment: yeah just wanted to consult with you people nothing else, anyway thanks

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is really about, to be honest. Is this about *storing* values that you calculated somewhere (in a query, in the client code etc.) or is this about static *computed columns* (columns that reside in tables but are actually formulas that are evaluated whenever you are querying them)?

Comment: I was not asking something just consulting with you people whether putting calculated values inside database is good or bad idea, and Andriy I was reading Salaryfield from table and deducting it from  all the payment that has been given to employee so that I can have advance or remaining salary, and at the beginning of next month i

Comment: This is really too ambiguous for Stack Overflow. Without code, it's just a hypothetical question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remaining Salaray = Salary - Advance. You need to put Salary and Advance inside database.

Comment: Now I got it, thanks everyone for help

Comment: accept as answer..if it helps you..

Comment: My opinion is that this is the right answer. Also, if you check the FAQ, you should see that StackOverflow is **not** a site for extended discussions.